# How to return value from function in protractor?

Tags: node.js, protractor, httprequest

```
  this.httpXsrf = function() {
    var token;
    var http = require("https");

    var options = {
        "method" : "GET",
        "hostname" : "infomatrix-ci.cmxdev.com",
        "port" : null,
        "path" : "/",
        "headers" : {
            "cache-control" : "no-cache",
        }
    };
     http.request(options, function(res) {
        var chunks = [];
        var setcookie = res.headers["set-cookie"];
        if (setcookie) {
            setcookie.forEach(
            function(cookiestr) {
                if (cookiestr.indexOf('XSRF-TOKEN') > -1) {
                    var a = cookiestr.split(';');
                    token = a[1].splice;
                }
            });
        }
        res.on("data", function(chunk) {
            chunks.push(chunk);
        });

        res.on("end", function() {
            var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
            console.log(body.toString());
        });
    }).end();
};
```

In above code i would like to return token variable from function and store it in antoher variable on test page,
like,

```
var token = apiPage.httpxsrf();
```

or

```
apiPage.httpxsrf().then(function(token){
  // call another function like apiPage.httplogin(token);
});
```

How can i return token and store in variable and call another function using token variable?